# Numerical differentiation issues

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, derivatives

I've been using this to compute the first order derivative's value of a function $f$ in a given point:
$$f'(x) = \frac{f(x+\epsilon) - f(x-\epsilon)}{2\epsilon}$$

For some $\epsilon = 0.0001$ or so.
But when I try to use the same formula for higher order derivatives it gives odd results

$$f''(x) = \frac{f'(x+\epsilon) - f'(x-\epsilon)}{2\epsilon}$$
$$f''(x) = \frac{\frac{f(x+\epsilon+\epsilon) - f(x-\epsilon+\epsilon)}{2\epsilon} - \frac{f(x+\epsilon-\epsilon) - f(x-\epsilon-\epsilon)}{2\epsilon}}{2\epsilon}$$

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Don't use previous derivatives to find higher-order ones. Use $f$ directly. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation#Higher_order_methods

Comment: Try [this](http://www.math.unl.edu/~s-bbockel1/833-notes/node23.html#4.1.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a $1,-2,1$ scheme

$$f''(x) = \frac{\frac{f(x+\epsilon+\epsilon) - f(x-\epsilon+\epsilon)}{2\epsilon} - \frac{f(x+\epsilon-\epsilon) - f(x-\epsilon-\epsilon)}{2\epsilon}}{2\epsilon}
= \frac{f(x+h) - 2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2},$$

with $h=2\epsilon$, which is [the first one here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Higher-order_differences). 
Here is a [list of alternatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficients).

Do you implement it with the additional two fractions and include "${}+\epsilon-\epsilon$"?

For what application and with program what do you use it?

Odd calculation of what kind or to what accuracy?

Comment: Thanks! The odd results were because of me, but I fixed it and using the formula you suggested I managed to increase accuracy. I need it for a school project on "Newton polynomial"